# Linux Newb ./config: No Such file or directory

Tags: linux, openssl, config

I'm new to Linux and I'm trying to install a program called OpenSSL. I'm following a guide and it says to download the tar file, so i created a directory called Website_Related with the path

```
~/Downloads/Website_Related
```

and downloaded the tar file from that directory with the command

```
wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2o.tar.gz
```

This went fine. Then the guide says to execute the following command

```
$ ./config \
--prefix=/opt/openssl \ 
--openssldir=/opt/openssl \
enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128
```

I tried executing this command from the same directory where I downloaded the file to and I get an error "No such file or directory". I also tried executing the command from my home directory and got the same error. The guide gives an explanation for the "enable-ec_nist_64_gcc_128" but not the rest of the command.

What is going on here? I did some research and saw . is often a directory having to do with configuration in your home directory, and I can see it in my home directory with

```
ls -a
```

command, but if i try to go into it with

```
cd .
```

that fails. Could someone please explain to me what this ./config command is attempting to do, and why it is failing?

Thank you.

Comment: It's generally `./configure`

Answer (score 1):

You need to unpack it first:

```
tar vxf openssl-1.0.2o.tar.gz
```